# append two different <div> tag to two different <image> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I am working with woocommerce plugin in wordpress.

My html code is:

```
<ul class="products">
<li>
   <a href="http://localhost/watch/product/88-rue-du-rhone/">
       <img class="attachment-shop_catalog wp-post-image" width="300" height="300" alt="88-rue-du-rhone_87wa120050_sku_402729_usp_30676" src="http://localhost/watch/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/88-rue-du-rhone_87wa120050_sku_402729_usp_30676.jpg">

       <img class="secondary-image attachment-shop-catalog" width="300" height="300" alt="88-rue-du-rhone_87wa120050_sku_402729_usp_30679" src="http://localhost/watch/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/88-rue-du-rhone_87wa120050_sku_402729_usp_30679.jpg">
   </a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Now, I have to add two different  to the two different image tag using jQuery. So what code should I have to write?

My jQuery code is :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".products li a").append($("<div class='main-img'></div>");
});
```

But div is not added.

Comment: Your title appears to be different to what your code is doing. Note that what your title says you're trying to do (put a `div` inside an `img`) is impossible. The issue in your jQuery example is a missing `)`. Fix that and your code appending a `div` to the `a` should work. Note that you need to put some content in the `.main-img` div for it to actually appear visible in the page: http://jsfiddle.net/ahxaofqh/

Comment: Your selector and your HTML does not match..

Comment: there does not seem to be anything with the class 'products', is code missing?

Comment: Did you want to wrap each image in a div? If yes, pls also edit you question's title accordingly to make it more clear as to what you're after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to wrap each image in a div, try the below js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".products li a img").wrap($("<div class='main-img'></div>"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you wanted to wrap each image inside of `a`. You may do so with the following.

```
$(".products li a > img").filter(function() {
    $(this).wrap("<div class='main-img'></div>");
});
```

OR

```
$(".products li a > img").wrap("<div class='main-img'></div>");
```

[**A Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/gzhaaomq/)

More about [`.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)